# Hibernate not respecting nullable=true in @JoinColumn annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Documents")
public class Document extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "asset_id")
    private Asset asset;


    @ManyToOne( targetEntity = Debt.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "debt__id")
    private Debt debt;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "debts")
public class Debt extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "debt", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Document> documents;
}
```

This mapping:

```
@ManyToOne( targetEntity = Debt.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "debt_id")
    private Debt debt;
```

was recently added.

On running the app, the app is crashing with an error saying: *Error executing DDL "alter table documents add debt__id bigint not null" via JDBC Statement*

I checked the sql query hibernate sent to the database and it was: *alter table documents add debt_id bigint not null*

This query fails because there are records already on the `documents` table so a non-nullable column without default value could not be added.

So why is the nullable=true in the @JoinColumn annotation ignored by hibernate.

I couldn't find an answer anywhere. This is a spring-boot app, if it helps.

Comment: `optional = false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the  `optional = false` from the `@ManyToOne`. That is the culprit. Also, you don't need to mention `nullable=true` in the `@JoinColumn`, that is by default `true`

```
@ManyToOne( targetEntity = Debt.class,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "debt__id")
private Debt debt;
```

Comment: Wao....it works....I didn't see that all...thanks very very much.